# What should "whether it is" be followed by?

Tags: grammar

Do I have to add the word "doing" to "a project at work" to make the three bold parts in the same form? Which version is better?

> They can use their first language to accomplish any task, whether it
> is **a project at work**, **ordering food at a restaurant** or
> **shopping at a grocery store**.

> They can use their first language to accomplish any task, whether it
> is ***doing* a project at work**, **ordering food at a restaurant** or
> **shopping at a grocery store**.

Comment: Colloquially, either is acceptable.

Comment: Colloquially or not, both are fine.

Comment: Pedantically, *...whether it **be** [fish or fowl or good red herring]* is "more acceptable".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. @FumbleFingers, do you mean that if I want it to be formal, it's better to use "whether it be doing a project at work..."?

Comment: That might depend on your definition of "formal". Use of the subjunctive in such contexts continues to decline, but almost certainly if you were asked to choose between ***is*** and ***be*** in an English test with this example, the examiner would be looking for ***be***.

Comment: Hello, everyone. How can I make text bold in the comment section?

Comment: "Whether it be" would be rare, but constructions involving "be it" are actually still in relatively common use.

Comment: @Learner110 surround text by ** (like `**bold text**`) for **bold**, or * (`*italic text*`) for *italic*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both forms are correct.

The structure of the first part of your sentence requires a list of noun phrases to come after "whether it is". These can be noun phrases with standard nouns like "a project at work", or noun phrases with a gerund like "ordering food at a restaurant". Grammatically, there's no difference since both are noun phrases, so they can appear as equivalent forms in a list of noun phrases.

This means both "a project at work" and "doing a project at work" are noun phrases and can appear in such a list, so both forms are correct.